# How to get array using nested foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, foreach

I'm getting data from json file of the website.

This is the example json data from the URL.

```
Array
(
    [1] => TEXT1
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sample1] => text1
                    [sample2] => text2
)
)
)
```

I've tried with this code.

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/file.json');
$datas = json_decode($json,true);        


foreach ($datas as $key => $row) {

            $data[] = $row;
            //unset($tempData[1])
            foreach ($datas as $key2 => $row1) {
                $data1[] = $row1;
                unset($data1[0]);
            }
        }

print_r($data1); exit;
```

I want to get the data of first array which is **TEXT1** and the other array data **sample1** and **sample2**

Comment: TEXT1 is a value! sample1 and sample2 are assoc array keys ?? Maybe if you show us what you are trying to get hold of, we might better understand the question

Comment: And what's the problem with the given code? Anything not working? If this is the case, what have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just sharing my answer to my question and its working now.

```
 foreach ($datas as $row) {
            $tempData = $row;
        }
        $json = json_encode($tempData);
        $array = json_decode($json, true);

        $lastArray = [];
        foreach ($array as $key => $row1){
            $lastArray[$key] = $row1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can retrieve the data by the square brackets according to its index inside the array.

you may read about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp

and to access to the wanted indexes here the code

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/file.json');
$data = json_decode($json,true);        

$data[1]  // TEXT1
$data[2][0]['sample1'] // sample1
$data[2][0]['sample2'] // sample1
```

To get the data dynamically you may use a recursive technique

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/file.json');
$data = json_decode($json,true);     
$newData = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data));   //  Standard PHP Library (SPL) 

print_r($newData);
```

Good luck,